# C (linux) passing array of structs to delete element

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I have the following issues in my C Program,

FIRST, I have the following structure,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct ts{
  char *fname;
  char *lname;
  char *fingers;
  char *toes;
};

void delelement(char *, struct ts *);
int i;

int main(int argc, char **argv){
  struct ts *ex=(struct ts*)malloc(sizeof(struct ts));

  ex[0].fname="joe";
  ex[0].lname="bob";
  ex[0].fingers="11";
  ex[0].toes="9";

  ex[1].fname="billy";
  ex[1].lname="bronco";
  ex[1].fingers="10";
  ex[1].toes="10";

  ex[2].fname="martha";
  ex[2].lname="sue";
  ex[2].fingers="12";
  ex[2].toes="20";

  delelement("billy", ex);

  return 0;
}
```

For debugging I loop through and print the values in the array of structs - this works (nevermind I'm not returning a value in this function - the problem I'm running into is before we even get to that).

```
void delelement(char *delwhat, struct ts *passedex){

  //struct ts *tempex=(struct ts*)malloc(sizeof(struct ts));
  for(i=0; i<sizeof(passedex)-1; i++){
    printf("passedex[%d].fname is %s\n", i, passedex[i].fname);    
    printf("passedex[%d].lname is %s\n", i, passedex[i].lname);
    printf("passedex[%d].fingers is %s\n", i, passedex[i].fingers);
    printf("passedex[%d].toes is %s\n", i, passedex[i].toes);
  }
  return;
}
```

now THAT works fine - prints out information correctly.

now let's simply remove the comment and define the temporary array of structs

```
void delelement(char *delwhat, struct ts *passedex){

  struct ts *tempex=(struct ts*)malloc(sizeof(struct ts));
  for(i=0; i<sizeof(passedex)-1; i++){
    printf("passedex[%d].fname is %s\n", i, passedex[i].fname);    
    printf("passedex[%d].lname is %s\n", i, passedex[i].lname);
    printf("passedex[%d].fingers is %s\n", i, passedex[i].fingers);
    printf("passedex[%d].toes is %s\n", i, passedex[i].toes);

  }
  return;
}
```

**BOOM - segfault**

```
passedex[0].fname is joe
passedex[0].lname is bob
passedex[0].fingers is 11
passedex[0].toes is 9
passedex[1].fname is billy
Segmentation fault
```

OK so I tried a different approach - which kind of works

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
struct ts{
  char *fname;
  char *lname;
  char *fingers;
  char *toes;
};
void delelement(char *, struct ts *, struct ts *);
int i;
int main(int argc, char **argv){
  struct ts *ex=(struct ts*)malloc(sizeof(struct ts));
  struct ts *tempex=(struct ts*)malloc(sizeof(struct ts));

  ex[0].fname="joe";
  ex[0].lname="bob";
  ex[0].fingers="11";
  ex[0].toes="9";
  ex[1].fname="billy";
  ex[1].lname="bronco";
  ex[1].fingers="10";
  ex[1].toes="10";
  ex[2].fname="martha";
  ex[2].lname="sue";
  ex[2].fingers="12";
  ex[2].toes="20";
  delelement("billy", ex, tempex);
  return 0;
}
void delelement(char *delwhat, struct ts *passedex, struct ts *tempex){
  //struct ts *tempex=(struct ts*)malloc(sizeof(struct ts));
  for(i=0; i<sizeof(passedex)-1; i++){
    printf("passedex[%d].fname is %s\n", i, passedex[i].fname);    
    printf("passedex[%d].lname is %s\n", i, passedex[i].lname);
    printf("passedex[%d].fingers is %s\n", i, passedex[i].fingers);
    printf("passedex[%d].toes is %s\n", i, passedex[i].toes);
  }
  return;
}
```

WORKS fine... (tempex now defined in main)

```
passedex[0].fname is joe
passedex[0].lname is bob
passedex[0].fingers is 11
passedex[0].toes is 9
passedex[1].fname is billy
passedex[1].lname is bronco
passedex[1].fingers is 10
passedex[1].toes is 10
passedex[2].fname is martha
passedex[2].lname is sue
passedex[2].fingers is 12
passedex[2].toes is 20
```

now lets start assigning values to *tempex - no segfault with tempex defined in main

```
void delelement(char *delwhat, struct ts *passedex, struct ts *tempex){

  //struct ts *tempex=(struct ts*)malloc(sizeof(struct ts));

  for(i=0; i<sizeof(passedex)-1; i++){
    printf("passedex[%d].fname is %s\n", i, passedex[i].fname);    
    printf("passedex[%d].lname is %s\n", i, passedex[i].lname);
    printf("passedex[%d].fingers is %s\n", i, passedex[i].fingers);
    printf("passedex[%d].toes is %s\n", i, passedex[i].toes);
    tempex[i].fname=passedex[i].fname;
    tempex[i].lname=passedex[i].lname;
    tempex[i].fingers=passedex[i].fingers;
    tempex[i].toes=passedex[i].toes;
  }
  return;
}
```

but NOW - weirdness

```
passedex[0].fname is joe
passedex[0].lname is bob
passedex[0].fingers is 11
passedex[0].toes is 9
passedex[1].fname is billy
passedex[1].lname is bronco
passedex[1].fingers is joe
passedex[1].toes is bob
passedex[2].fname is 11
passedex[2].lname is 9
passedex[2].fingers is billy
passedex[2].toes is bronco
```

I am getting errors here. The goal is to have a dynamic array of structures containing char *'s. Once past this issue, there will be an instance in main (or wherever) that I wish to delete one of those structures.

What I was going for was something like,

```
struct ts* delelement(char *delwhat, struct ts *passedex, struct ts *tempex){

  //struct ts *tempex=(struct ts*)malloc(sizeof(struct ts));

  for(i=0; i<sizeof(passedex)-1; i++){
    printf("passedex[%d].fname is %s\n", i, passedex[i].fname);    
    printf("passedex[%d].lname is %s\n", i, passedex[i].lname);
    printf("passedex[%d].fingers is %s\n", i, passedex[i].fingers);
    printf("passedex[%d].toes is %s\n", i, passedex[i].toes);
    //load tempex with everything except the one I want to delete
    if(!(passedex[i].fname==delwhat)){
      tempex[i].fname=passedex[i].fname;
      tempex[i].lname=passedex[i].lname;
      tempex[i].fingers=passedex[i].fingers;
      tempex[i].toes=passedex[i].toes;
    }
  }
  free(passedex); //haven't got here yet - dunno if needed
  //realloc if needed - gotta get here first - pass segfault and/or jumbled data

  for(i=0; i<sizeof(passedex)-1; i++){
    passedex[i].fname=tempex[i].fname;
    passedex[i].lname=tempex[i].lname;
    passedex[i].fingers=tempex[i].fingers;
    passedex[i].toes=tempex[i].toes;
  }

  return passedex;
}
```

So it would create (or have) a temporary array of structs to work with... load that array minus the one to be deleted... reload the passed array of structs and pass it back.

Comment: Can you use the code sample markup {} in the editor when pasting your C code? It's really hard to read this way.

Answer (score 2):

You only allocated one struct, not 3 as you think.

You should do something like :

```
struct ts *ex = malloc( sizeof(struct ts) * 3 );
```

What you do is OK with the `const char` (string literal) assignments. But you should change your definition of `struct ts` to:

```
struct ts{
  const char *fname;
  const char *lname;
  const char *fingers;
  const char *toes;
};
```

This way your compiler will warn you if you try to change the contents of those strings.

Otherwise you can use `malloc()` and `strcpy()` for your `char*`'s in the `struct`.And

```
ex[0].fname = malloc(sizeof(char) * 128);
//...
strcpy(ex[0].fname , "myString");
//...
```

Also :

This code snippet looks a bit weird

```
void delelement(char *delwhat, struct ts *passedex){

  for(i=0; i<sizeof(passedex)-1; i++){
      //...
  }
  return;
}
```

I think you mean

```
void delelement(char *delwhat, struct ts *passedex , int array_size)
{
    int i;
    for( i=0 ; i < array_size ; i++ )
    {
         //...
```

You need to pass the size of the array as an argument. You may find some posts on this link interesting : [newbie questions about malloc and sizeof](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1533519/newbie-questions-about-malloc-and-sizeof)

Comment: You need to allocate memory before strcpy'ing into a char* too.

Comment: @florin, which part did I forgot ?

Comment: wrong. why should he allocate the struct char ptrs? his sample is clear, he assigns a const char* to the struct field fname and so on, he doesnt memcpy; you use malloc() before making that assignment you'll get a true segfault bloodshed :P :P :P no downvote for pointing the 3-struct malloc mess ;)

Comment: @adirau , what do you mean `you use malloc() before making that assignment you'll get a true segfault bloodshed` ? If you were to `strcpy()` you should first use `malloc()` and then `strcpy()`.

Comment: citing: "You never allocated memory in your struct's chars, hence the Undefined Behaviour - SegFault." ; he really doesn't want to malloc his char * struct members; he's just operating on them with const char * assignments, no copying; he does make a mess later by interreferencing char *s, etc but those don't cause the segfault; only the bad ts struct malloc does;

Comment: was going for dynamic allotment

at first I was approaching this whole thing with a multidimensional char *

such as char *people[][3];

This is where I got into a rut and turned to the struct. I forget now what the exact issue was with the multidimensional array, but there was some issue where I instead turned to a struct of char *'s.

What I am wanting to achieve is to get some sort of global "tracking" multidimentional array, or array of structs that will hold 4 bits of information. The goal is to be able to access this from anywhere across the board, and to be able to delete one and

Comment: the others into that space... so if I have

`joe, bob, 11, 9`     
`billy, bob, 10 ,10`     
`mary, sue, 12, 14`

and then delete billy bob... i do not have

`joe, bob, 11, 9`
`null, null, null, null`
`mary, sue, 12, 14`

but have

`joe, bob, 11, 9`
`mary, sue, 12, 14`


Going for dynamic allocation because at any time there can be any number of "people"

Comment: @user, maybe you should use a linked list instead.

Answer (score 1):

you are allocating space only for one ts struct

```
struct ts *ex=(struct ts*)malloc(sizeof(struct ts));
```

fact that you can access and work fine with the memory after your allocated space it's just pure luck

Answer (score 1):

Next problem:

```
for(i=0; i<sizeof(passedex)-1; i++){
```

The `sizeof` operator does not return the number of element in an array, it returns the number of bytes *one* passedex occupies. As this is a pointer, it will have a value like 4 or 8, depending on the kind of machine you are using.

In fact, in C, there is no way of knowing how big an array, if all you have is a pointer to it. This means that you have to pass in new parameter informing your routine how big the array is.